# Is it possible to put a button in a NatTable?

Tags: java, nattable, nebula

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X0mOM.png)

Is it possible to put a button in the table like the attached image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NatTable is a custom painted table control. Putting real buttons in the table is possible, but actually does not really make sense and could even lead to resource issues in larger tables.

You can actually render anything if you have a corresponding painter. And for a button you of course also need the action binding. NatTable has the `ButtonCellPainter` to render a cell as a button. But actually the implementation to mimik the button press is a bit outdated IMHO. The corresponding example should give you an idea what you can do and how to do it.

https://git.eclipse.org/c/nattable/org.eclipse.nebula.widgets.nattable.git/tree/org.eclipse.nebula.widgets.nattable.examples/src/org/eclipse/nebula/widgets/nattable/examples/examples/_102_Configuration/Rendering_cells_as_a_link_and_button.java